# Cryptographically secure pseudo random shuffle a list or array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, cryptography

I am in need of a shuffle function that uses CSPRNG (Cryptographically Secure Pseudo Random Number Generator) and can be seeded manually for the same output for the same seed.

The built-in `random.shuffle()` [in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) can be manually seeded but is [not suitable for cryptographic use](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#module-random) and will be removed in version 3.11 of python.

`Crypto.Random.random.shuffle()` [from PyCryptodome](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/random/random.html#Crypto.Random.random.shuffle) does not accept a seed as far as I can gather.

Currently, I have settled for the Mersenne Twister used by the built-in `random.shuffle()` function to shuffle a list of numbers but this is far from ideal. Shuffling a numpy array is also welcome as the built-in `numpy.random.shuffle` [is not suitable for cryptographic purposes](https://www.sharpsightlabs.com/blog/numpy-random-seed/).
The array/list may have elements upwards of 10 billion so performance and randomness are key.

The bandaid code is below.

```
import numpy as np
from random import seed, shuffle
array = np.arange(10) # [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
print(array)
seed(1)
shuffle(array)
print(array) # [6 8 9 7 5 3 0 4 1 2]
```

Comment: As you have found, a good CSPRNG does not depend on the seed.  It pulls randomness/entropy from many different sources, only one of which may be the seed.  It is cryptographically secure because you cannot reset it back to a previous state, which means you cannot get the same sequence of outputs from it.  Allowing that would be a cryptographic vulnerability as the attacker could then regenerate your secret sequence of numbers.

Comment: I see. Would you stand by the Mersenne Twister or recommend some other pseudo random number generator given that dependency on the seed is a requirement?

Comment: MT is good for non-cryptographic purposes.  However if your initial seeds are almost the same then the two generated sequences will be almost the same initially, though they will eventually diverge.  Basically when you do change the seed, don't just add 1.

Comment: What are your thoughts on [Cryptographic DRBG](https://csrc.nist.gov/glossary/term/Deterministic_Random_Bit_Generator)? I would wager they would also function well here but I am unaware of anything that can be used in Python unless you have any suggestion? As for the seed, it's a 512bit hash of a secret so that should introduce the required entropy.

Comment: The NIST RNGs/RBGs are cryptographically secure, in that the reseed function prevents going backwards because it adds new entropy into the mix every so often.  You would have to develop your own version that did not reseed and so would not be cryptographically secure, though it would allow a repeat of the output after the seed was reset.

Answer (score 4):

CSPRNG's often have problems with re-seeding and such, drawing entropy from an entropy pool within the operating system during operation. So instead it is better to use a stream cipher, e.g. AES in counter mode.

Then it is also important that the shuffle operation always is performed in the same way. Similarly, the numbers from the generated bit stream should always operate in the same way. If those are optimized or otherwise changed the result will be a different shuffle, breaking the scheme.

In the end you are better off programming this yourself, so you are sure that the code behind the method contracts doesn't change.

The requirements for this are:

- a stream cipher with a seed the size of the key;
- an implementation of "rejection sampling" to get random numbers in a range;
- the Fisher-Yates shuffle to create a fully random shuffle.

It is possible to hash the seed and take the leftmost bytes if the size is not compliant with the stream cipher.

---

Demonstration of the idea (not fully tested or well-designed):

```
import numpy as np
from Crypto.Cipher import ChaCha20
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes

array = np.arange(100) # [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

seed = bytes([0x00]) * 32 # use SHA-256 to hash different size seeds

nonce_rfc7539 = bytes([0x00]) * 12
cipher = ChaCha20.new(key=seed, nonce=nonce_rfc7539)
zerobuf = bytes([0x00]) * 5

def sample(max):
    # rejection sampling using rand(0..n * max) % max
    # the value 2 is in there to make sure the number of bits is at least
    # two higher than max, so that the chance of each candicate succeeding
    # is higher
    stream_size = (max.bit_length() + 2 + 7) // 8
    max_stream_value = 1 << (stream_size * 8)
    max_candidate = max_stream_value - max_stream_value % max
    while True:
        stream = cipher.encrypt(zerobuf[0:stream_size])
        candidate = int.from_bytes(stream, "big")
        if (candidate < max_candidate):
            break
    return candidate % max

def shuffle(list):
    # do the Fisher-Yates shuffle
    for i in range(len(list) - 1, 0, -1):
        j = sample(i + 1)
        list[i],list[j] = list[j],list[i]

# test only
print(array)
for i in range(0, 100):
    shuffle(array)
    print(array)
```

Comment: Would a stream cipher like XChaCha20-Poly1305 suffice? Does an AES-GCM-SIV CTR mode variant exist?
How would one begin coding such a system? I've always been told to never use a homemade cryptography system and the devil is always within the details when it comes to cryptography.

Comment: Just the (X)ChaCha20 would be a stream cipher, yes. AES-GCM always uses AES-CTR mode as stream cipher mode. You don't need the integrity / authentication of an AEAD cipher. I'm afraid the "build it yourself" is kind of implied with these kind of requirements :| Of course, many things are open source now, so if you want to make sure that the shuffling is performed correctly maybe you can copy and repurpose the current shuffle method.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I have gotten hold of a library of AES-CTR and the output of that is in bytes (values in range of 0-255). I am not sure how to apply it in cases for say I have numbers greater than 255, or even floats for that matter. I'm sure there is a way but my searching fails me. Can you suggest what I can do or where I should be looking?

Comment: Yes, best to look at existing implementations. What you are looking for is called "rejection sampling".

Answer (score 2):

[SECRETS](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) module contains CSPRNG based functions like CHOICE, which returns a randomly-chosen element. So you could use this function in Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm implementation like this one:

```
import secrets

x_list = list(range(256))
y_list = []

print(x_list)

while len(x_list) > 0:
    picked_item = secrets.choice(x_list)
    y_list.append(picked_item)
    x_list.remove(picked_item)

print(y_list)
```

Not sure about the performance and if it will handle well such a big list. It took 2.5 min to shuffle the list containing 256000 elements. But for less demanding applications it might do the job.