# Use Fernet/os.urandom key to generate passwords

Tags: python, cryptography

So I made a password Generator

```
char = random.choice(string.punctuation)
numb = str(random.randrange(0, 10))
upper = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
lower1 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
lower2 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
lower3 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
lower4 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
lower5 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
lower6 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
lower7 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
print("Your randomly generated password is:",
char + numb + upper + lower1 + lower2 + lower3 + lower4 + lower5 + lower6 +lower7)
```

Then I got sucked into a wormhole of cryptography, I have the library installed and played around with creating an encrypted key using fernet.

After tinkering for a few hours, I've hit a wall.

I want to use the cryptographically random byte that fern gives me to build my password with but the passwords are 44 characters long and sometimes don't include capitals/symbols etc.

I *tried* :

```
p = os.random(4)
```

This solved the length issue but it still spits out unusable passwords sometimes.

How can I use `os.urandom` to build a viable 12char password

(1 Uppercase, 1 Lowercase, 1 symbol, 1 number)

Comment: Do you want to only use `os.urandom`. Because your code can be simplified to a good enough solution.

Comment: Try [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) instead. Terrible name, but I guess `random`   was already taken. Note that if you start counting in variable names then you're doing it wrong: the computer should do the counting, not you :)

Comment: You may want to securely shuffle your string if you want to have a specific number of items within the password, by the way. [Here's a way to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66620108/589259) but replace the `sample`  with the `secrets.belowThingy` method.

Answer (score 1):

**Thanks to those who gave me ideas I found an answer myself**

While I was unable to find a way to convert the Fernet byte data into passwords directly, I did an even deeper dive into cryptography and learned just what made something truly random vs pseudo random.

The following code is what I settled on for anyone in the future who has the same question I did.

**What it does:**

- Takes an input from the user
- Checks to see if that input is an integer
- Then rounds the number down to the nearest integer divisible by 4
- Finally it generates an upper/lower/digit/punctuation in sequence.

It was a fun project and I'll be sure to revisit it soon to make it simpler and more efficient, if you have any ideas don't be shy to drop me a comment!

```
    # Cryptographically generated random password
    
    import random
    import string

    # Start Passgen

    print("Please input a max-character limit for required password")
    size = input()
    try:
        val = int(size)
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not an int!")

    else:
        print("Input accepted, Now generating password...")

    # Generate the Password
    def pass_gen():

        uletters = string.ascii_uppercase
        lletters = string.ascii_lowercase
        digits = string.digits
        punctuation = string.punctuation
        chars = (uletters, lletters, digits, punctuation)
        p = ''

        for i in range(int(size)//4):

    p += ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choices(uletters, k=1))
    p += ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choices(lletters, k=1))
    p += ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choices(digits, k=1))
    p += ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choices(punctuation, k=1))
        print("Your randomly generated password is: " + p)

        #Run the function
        pass_gen()
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use `os.urandom` specifically to build a password that have specific specifications which are at least one upper, one lower, one number and 1 symbol.

```
import os

alphabet = 'qwertyuioplkjhgfdaszxcvbnmQAZWSXEDCRFVTGBYHNUJMIKLOP0123456789!@#$%^&*()'
upper = 'QAZWSXEDCRFVTGBYHNUJMIKLOP'
lower = 'qwertyuioplkjhgfdaszxcvbnm'
numbers = '0123456789'
symbols = '!@#$%^&*()'

length = len(alphabet)
password = ''
password_length = 10
for x in range(password_length):
    password += alphabet[int.from_bytes(os.urandom(1), byteorder="big") % length]

flags = []
for x in upper:
    if x in password:
        flags.append(1)
        break

for x in lower:
    if x in password:
        flags.append(1)
        break

for x in numbers:
    if x in password:
        flags.append(1)
        break

for x in symbols:
    if x in password:
        flags.append(1)
        break

if len(flags) == 4:
    print("your password is ready: ", password)
```

since the password is first generated randomly then checked to see if it meets certain criteria sometime the tests will fail especially if password length is low which you would have to run the program again.

Comment: Just saw this now I found another solution but I appreciate the work you did, I think I'll give the int from bytes a shot to actually get the Fernet keygen converting to password strings soon :O!