# Check for special characters in Python while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, special-characters

Below is code for a password generator which I've written using Python3 and tkinter. I'm having difficulty with the last line of code `and any(c in spec for c in password)`. The while loop does not terminate when I add this last line to the if statement in the while loop. I've looked at all the other answers online for "check string for special characters" and can't find a solution to make my while loop work. The last line of my code should check if there is any special characters in the password, if not, then generate password again.

```
import string
import secrets

alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
spec = string.punctuation
while True:
    password = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(12))
    if (any(c.islower() for c in password)
        and any(c.isupper() for c in password)
        and any(c.isdigit() for c in password)
        and any(c in spec for c in password)):
        break
```

Comment: the code u posted works, i don't think its the cause

Comment: @PyxlDavon You are right, I checked again, and for some reason unknown to me the code now breaks and creates a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `and any(c in spec for c in password)` does in fact work. After PyxlDavon pointed out that my code does work, I closed and restarted my python interpreter and the code did work. So my only conclusion is that my python interpreter became unstable for some unkown reason. I haven't seen this code style in any other related questions. I apologize for answering my own question. I got the idea for this code from this link: [https://www.codespeedy.com/detect-if-a-string-contains-special-characters-or-not-in-python/#:~:text=To%20check%20if%20a%20string,special%20characters%20from%20the%20string](https://www.codespeedy.com/detect-if-a-string-contains-special-characters-or-not-in-python/#:%7E:text=To%20check%20if%20a%20string,special%20characters%20from%20the%20string).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to generate a fully random password and if this doesn't meet your criteria, start over.

This is an **inefficient strategy**, which can cause your loop to run **many** times (although here it shouldn't be too bad for 1 character of each and 12 characters total).

You want 12 characters with at least 1 (or n) lower/upper/digit/special, so pick randomly as many of each as wanted and fill the rest with any character, then shuffle and join.

The [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) module does not have convenience functions such as `choices`/`sample`/`shuffle` of [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html), so the generation is a bit more lengthy.

Example with different constraints (at least 4 uppercase and 3 digits, 1 lowercase, 1 special)

```
# constraints
length = 12

pools = {'LC': string.ascii_lowercase,
         'UC': string.ascii_uppercase,
         'D' : string.digits,
         'P' : string.punctuation,
        }

min_num = {'LC': 1, 'UC': 4, 'D': 3, 'P': 1}

assert length >= sum(min_num.values())

alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation

# password generation
# step1: get random chars meeting the constraints
L = length
chars = []
for k,n in min_num.items():
    chars.extend(secrets.choice(pools[k]) for _ in range(n))
    L -= n

chars.extend(secrets.choice(alphabet) for _ in range(L))

# step2: shuffle the characters and join
# disclaimer: I don't know if this method is cryptographically secure
#             comments on that would be greatly appreciated
# see an alternative here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66528995
shuffled_chars = []
for i in range(length, 0, -1):
    shuffled_chars.append(chars.pop(secrets.randbelow(i)))

password = ''.join(shuffled_chars)

print(password)
```

Example outputs:

```
1ENSY55DPp+N
9%O)5GF7ntKV
0&EQL2VV4M6f
```