# Check if a character is not in a string (pyt

Tags: python

```py
password = "e"
if any(c in password for c in "abcd"):
   print("yes")
```

I am trying to write a code that allows me to check if a character "e", is not included in "abcd".

However, the code above only prints yes if there's an occurrence in the password of `a`, `b`, `c`, or `d`. I don't know how to change it to have: If there's any occurrence of a character not present in `abcd`, in the password, then it returns yes.

(note if the password is `"ea"` for example, it should print "yes" as well)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Sounds like you want `if any(c not in 'abcd' for c in password):`.  Alternatively, you can write this as a set difference: `if set(password) - set('abcd'):`

Comment: *If there's any occurence of a character not present in "abcd"* - that is a very complicated way of explaining things and I don't think I understand it... Could you please explain it differently and/or provide more examples?

Comment: or `if not all(c in 'abcd' for c in password):`

Comment: Same homework assignment as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74162292/check-for-special-characters-in-python-while-loop) ?

Comment: From the question I read `if not any(c in password for c in "abcd"):`.

Answer (score 1):

`any` takes an iterable. It expects a True. Statement so you should use `not in` rather than `in`. Because if not in you want it to say True, not in.

```
if any([c, if c not in 'abcd' for c in password]):
    print("yes")
```